# Dynamically access TextField in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield

I am creating a TextField dynamically inside VStack. Here TextFields are created as follows:

```swift
struct Input: View {
    
    var title: String
    @State var value:String
    var disableInputMode:Bool = true

    var body: some View {                
        VStack {
            Text(title)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .foregroundColor(Color("SecondaryTextColor"))
            TextField("", text: $value)
                .disabled(disableInputMode)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            Divider()
        }
        .padding()        
    }
}
```

and these TextFields depend on some other data fields (which are decided at run time):

```swift
ScrollView {
    VStack {
        ForEach(detailsViewModel.details) { datum in
            Input(title: datum.title, value: datum.detail!)
        }
    }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    .padding()
}.background(Color("Light"))
.cornerRadius(25)
.padding()
```

Now, when a user enters data and tries to apply, I couldn't find how to get those inputs from other views. From the example in this case — from the above view.

Comment: You must store your state in a level at or above where you need to access it. Move the state out of the child view and into the parent view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1 (iOS 14 *)

Use [onChange](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onchange(of:perform:)) modifier to detect TextField value changes and update it to your model.

```
struct Input: View {
    
    var title: String
    @State var value:String
    var disableInputMode:Bool = false
    
    var onTextChange: ((String) -> Void)?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(title)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .foregroundColor(Color("SecondaryTextColor"))
            TextField("", text: $value)
                .onChange(of: value) {
                    // Called each time value changes.
                    if onTextChange != nil {
                        onTextChange!($0)
                    }
                }
                .disabled(disableInputMode)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            Divider()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

### Solution 2 (iOS 13 *)

Extend Binding to handle custom onChange

```
extension Binding {
    func onChange(_ handler: @escaping (Value) -> Void) -> Binding<Value> {
        Binding(
            get: { self.wrappedValue },
            set: { newValue in
                self.wrappedValue = newValue
                handler(newValue)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Then your **Input View** become

```
struct Input: View {
    
    var title: String
    @State var value:String
    var disableInputMode:Bool = false
    
    var onTextChange: ((String) -> Void)?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(title)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .foregroundColor(Color("SecondaryTextColor"))
            TextField("", text: $value.onChange(textChanged))
                .disabled(disableInputMode)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            Divider()
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    func textChanged(to value: String) {
        // Called each time value changes.
        if onTextChange != nil {
            onTextChange!(value)
        }
    }
}
```

### How to use:

Both solutions you can use your **Input View** like follows.

```
ScrollView {
    VStack {
        ForEach(detailsViewModel.details) { datum in
            Input(title: datum.title, value: datum.detail) { newValue in
                // Each time you will get the update
                // Do what ever you want to do with the new value
                // something like
                // detailsViewModel.update(value: newValue, forItem: datum.id)
                print("Text value for \(datum.id) :", newValue)
            }
        }
    }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    .padding()
}.background(Color("Light"))
.cornerRadius(25)
.padding()
```

Comment: how to handle this for ios13? onChange is not available for for ios 13

Comment: Updated the answer to work with iOS 13